"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." drf
I'm doing a pet project. And I need to make that only authorized users can make POST/PATCH requests, and that only the owners of items can change/delete them.
views.py(item_app)
class CreateItemView(APIView):

    serializer_class = CreateItemSerializer
    authentication_classes=[OwnAuthentication]
    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOnwerOrReadOnly]
                       ... code ...

permissions.py(item_app)
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOnwerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.owner == request.user

authentication.py(auth_app)
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions

class OwnAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
            username = request.data.get('username')
            if not username:
                  return None
            try:
                  user= User.object.get(username=username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                  raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')
            return (user, None)

settings.py

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "auth_app.Users"

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}

[Authorization is done via JWT tokens, at login I get access token and copy it and paste it into header “Authorization” in postman, and when I enable this header there is still an errorenter image description here]1

In your settings.py , JWTAuthentication is set to the default authentication class.

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}


However, if you look at the last part of your question, it says that JWT authentication is used, but CreateItemView uses a different authentication class.
class CreateItemView(APIView):

    serializer_class = CreateItemSerializer
    # authentication_classes=[OwnAuthentication]
    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOnwerOrReadOnly]

To use the JWT certification class for CreateItemView, clear authentication_classes.
And to apply multiple permission classes, you need to use the bit operator.
class CreateItemView(APIView):

    serializer_class = CreateItemSerializer
    authentication_classes=[OwnAuthentication]
    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly|IsOnwerOrReadOnly]
    # or
    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly&IsOnwerOrReadOnly]


Finally, if you look at the last picture you provided, the token type was not specified in the value you delivered. your project used JWT Authentication, you need to add 'Bearer' to the beginning and give access_token.
Authorization: 'Bearer {access_token}'

when i add Bearer 'token' i I got an error.             "message": "Token is invalid or expired"

What did you use as authentication classes?

What do you mean? in authentication classes I only had my auth class and rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication

CreateItemView uses OwnAuthentication as an authentication class, right?
If so, I don't understand your last words very well (Authorization is done via JWT talkens, ...) In this section, it is described as using JWT Authentication.

@Antonly Yes, it's just that I don't fully understand the principles of authorization in django (or at all). After all, when I was looking for an answer to my question, I found that I need to make my own authentication class

There is no problem using JWTAuthentication if you want to achieve the goal described by the questioner.(I need to make that only authorized users can make POST/PATCH requests, and that only the owners of items can change/delete them)
